# selecting certain elements in a list - python

Tags: python, list

I am looking to edit elements in a list bar one element - I am wondering how to do so? I am making one element go up, the one selected, and the others to go down. I have worked out how to do the first bit, just not the second. Here is my code so far

```
score = [70,60,80]
action = ["one person off", 2, 200]

def take_action(score, action):
    x = action[1]
    if action[0] = "one person off":
        score[x] += 30
```

I am looking for 80 to go to 110 and the others to go down by 10 each.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean to add an `else:` part to the `if` statement with `score[x] -= 10` in it?

Comment: @mkrieger1 no, I want it to both happen, so want score[x] += 30 and the something underneath that would represent elements that are not score[x] going down by 10 - sorry new to stack overflow

Answer (score 1):

You could implement the action as loop:

```
for i,s in enumerate(score):
    score[i] = s+30 if i == x else s-10
```

Comment: thank you very much! this has worked spot on!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
score = [value+30 if i==x else value-10 for i,value in enumerate(score)]
```

This will give you back a new list, with the `x`th element increased by 30 and the others decreased by 10.

In order to modify the list that was passed in (rather than creating a new local variable named `score`) you would need to perform the assignment slightly differently:

```
score[:] = [value+30 if i==x else value-10 for i,value in enumerate(score)]
```

Comment: This will not update the score variable passed as parameter because it creates a new list in a local variable (also named score).

Comment: @AlainT. Ah, you're correct. I was assuming there was a return that wasn't shown, but that may be a bad assumption.

Comment: you could assign `score[:] = ...` instead and it would work.